# MegaSync freezes on firefox and doesn't recognise on chromium

Tags: firefox, chromium, mega

I have installed Mega Sync on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine.

```
sudo dpkg -i megasync-xUbuntu_14.04_amd64.deb
```

I have signed in to my Mega Account but when I try to download a file using Firefox, Mega Sync freezes.

In chromium its doesn't even recognise the installed software. Suggesting me to download the file and install it

Comment: Please forward the details of your issue to support@mega.nz for further assistance. We will need to examine your logs to see what is going on. Thank you.

Comment: @MegaSupport since AskUbuntu is a public support site, it's generally best to have a public conversation, either in the comments or in chat, so that other users might benefit from the info provided.

Comment: @MegaSupport yes Zacharee1 is right. You don't have to reply to same questions again and again this way. People with same errors can look on Google and it would find this post :)

Comment: @MegaSupport how do I get the logs. I can post them here if its doesn't contain sensitive information?

Answer (score 1):

For now, we can offer these temporary solutions:

OPTION A

This installer (no need to uninstall the previous one):

https://mega.nz/#!NVQ0hS5A!a9bDFny67f7C7A8XQ1sQEw0tdl1COX_PkEICBGZXwUI

This one prevents megasync from freezing (download will fail tough)

OPTION B

Manually add CA-certificates.

Steps:
    1) Save certificates 
https://knowledge.rapidssl.com/support/ssl-certificate-support/index?page=content&actp=CROSSLINK&id=SO26457 
    and 
    https://www.geotrust.com/resources/root_certificates/certificates/GeoTrust_Global_CA.pem

```
into /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ with .crt extension
```

2) update system certificates with:
        sudo update-ca-certificates

We are working on a permanent solution.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, Could you provide a reference for this (if there any public bug report entry), If this is confirmed then we may close the question as off-topic (bug report)